# ListView Selector not working with ListViewItem's background set

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that has a selector set with just a solid color.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/assignmentSelectedItem" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/assignmentsListView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/assignment_list_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

assignment_list_selector.xml -

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
 <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

In the `ListView.Adapter` for my list, I have items that have their view's background set to a specific color.  My question would be is that why the selector is not working at all in displaying a selected color for my list view?  If so, any suggestion of a work around with allowing me to still set the view's background color.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use ListView property `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in your layout .xml file in order to made list view to draw the selector over the list item rather than under them.

If you wonna have item's background + list selector functionality you can try another approach: Use transparent list selector. And modify your selector in order to use as a background for the list item. For example

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/your_list_item_color"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just overlay a solid color over top the item not allowing you to see the controls while the item is selected?

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check whether it suits you better?

Comment: That would work with a constant background color, but if the item's background color changes between three options, like red/yellow/green, then I would be back in the same boat. Any suggestions with that?

Comment: do you mean changes while selection is performing, or some items have red background, the others - green and the thirds - yellow?

Comment: some items could have green background, other red or yellow.

Comment: so the simplest solution is to define each background separately and apply to the appropriate item according to the your application logic. The second approach is to extend [StateListDrawable class that selector is a resource pointer to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). See [StateListDrawable documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) for more info.